# How to add plus one position to setSelectionRange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move cursor one more position to the right in input.

```
var start = this.selectionStart,
    end = this.selectionEnd;

this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
```

This works for keeping position in the same place after input value changed, but iam trying to add one more position to it, because my format code add "-" character after 4 chars.

```js
    $("input[name=login-access-token]").keypress(function(event){
        var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;
        console.log(start);
        var input = $(this).val();
        input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');
        var split = 4;
        var chunk = [];

        
        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {
            split = 4;
            chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
        }

        var test = [];
        chunk.forEach(element => {
            test.push(element.match(/.{1,4}/g));
        });
        
        test.forEach(element => {
            if(element.length!=4){
                $(this).val(function() {
                    var out = chunk.join("-").toUpperCase();

                    if(out.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8){
                            out += "-";
                    }

                    if(out.length == 9 && event.keyCode != 8 ){
                            out += "-";
                    }
                    
                    return out;
                });
            }
        });

        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.addRange(1);
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="login-access-token" placeholder="Code" />
```

```
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.addRange(1); //not working :/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Just add +1 to start and end which is values what we get from selectionStart.

```
 if(out.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8){
                        out += "-";
                        start = start+1;
                        end = end +1;
                }

                if(out.length == 9 && event.keyCode != 8 ){
                        out += "-";
                        start = start+1;
                        end = end +1;
                }
```